React player + mui slider bug on iphone
I have problem with react-player + mui slider. When I'm using it on the iphone It can jump to back miliseconds but on android it works good. How to fix it?
I thought this problem with slider but I noticed main react player has same problem on the iphone
enter image description here
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/silly-https-mkcxcn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A64%2C35

Can you explain the problem in more detail - what is the expected outcome behavior and what is the current behavior? On my device it seems to work well.

@Dimitar , the problem is on ios platform, when we deployed project, react player on androind and others works good but on ios react player has this problem. There is one moment, when we tested project on codesandbox, this project worked good on iphone. We want to get player without this problem, because this problem brings with it another problems only on iphone

I don't know if this has anything to do with the components you are using or not, but Apple has specific Date and Time formats. I have run into problems before where timestamps were returning NaN:NaN:NaN on Apple devices.

@Dimitar, oh it's interesting i will test it

@Dimitar, this problem is now) I managed to load this problem, but i can't fix it
